# can't read environment viables in a dockerized react app

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, vite

I created a demo react app using
`npm create vite`

I changed the `App.tsx` as follow :

```
function App() {

  console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')
  console.log(JSON.stringify(import.meta.env))
  console.log('!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!')

  return (
    <h1>MY APP</h1>
  )
}

export default App
```

I want to pass several environment variables, notably the backend URL.
I have tried to pass it in multiple ways.

my `Dockerfile` :

```
FROM nginx:latest AS BASE

# trying setting variable in dockerfile
ENV REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL5=http://www.five.com

# trying to take varibles from environment or args, as I have seen in different posts
ARG REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL1
ARG REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL3
ENV REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL1 $REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL1
ENV REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL3 $REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL3

#delete default welcome page
RUN rm -rf /user/share/nginx/html/*

# copying the built app
COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html

# exposing the port where nginx is listening to the outside
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

my `docker-compose.yml` :

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  myapp:
    container_name: app_front
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL3=http://www.three.com
        - REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL4=http://www.four.com
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL1=http://www.one.com
      - REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL2=http://www.two.com
```

how I run the app :

```
npm run build
docker-compose up
```

when opening a terminal in the newly created container,

```
echo $REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL<NUMBER>
```

returns the expected value for all variables but #4.
so the variables were indeed set in the container.
however, when opening `localhost:8080` and looking in the console, I can only see
`{"BASE_URL":"/","MODE":"production","DEV":false,"PROD":true,"SSR":false}`

what is my problem?
thanks

Comment: Read https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode, `REACT_APP_` is for [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/). But note also that those need to be set _at build time_, the actual React code is running **in your users' browsers** not on the Nginx server, and has no access to the env there.

Comment: _(Why this is a problem and what to do instead: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html)_

Answer (score 2):

Vite and other build tools read your environment variables and replace their references in your code with its value. Meaning: The value from build time is already hardcoded into your JavaScript build and can only be changed with a lot of effort. This is because the JavaScript runs in the Browser of your user and the user does not have access to the env vars in your docker container.

What do you do now?
You need to get your backend url from somewhere else somehow.
There are multiple ways to achieve it.
I don't know if this can be called a best practice, but here is how I usually achieve a react build that can be configured at runtime:

1. I create a middleware in my backend that returns a config meant for your frontend when I open a url ending with /config.json. Inside it is a calculated/configured backend-url
2. Every time I open my react page the browser makes a request to <current_url>/config.json (nginx has to be configured to redirect /config.json to your backend; use a hardcoded url in dev)
3. Browser (react code) saves the received url and uses it for every future request

Comment: You could probably configure nginx to return a config without asking the backend server when seeing /config.json at the end, but I never tried it